# JavaScript to create a dropdown list and get the selected value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

I need to add a dropdown list to a webpage.
generally the HTML code is like this;

```
<select id="au_1_sel" name="au_1_sel" class="searchw8">
    <option value="AU" selected="">method1</option>
    <option value="FI">method2</option>
</select>
```

How can I use JavaScript to create a element like above.
after I create this drop down list. I need to add it after a button.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button1");
```

and I already get the button element.
Also, when the button is clicked, I want to know which option the people have choose in the dropdown list. How can I do that using JavaScript.

I try this

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.id = "wayToCalculate";
//select.name="au_1_sel";
//select.class=class="searchw8";

var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value="1";
option1.selected="";
option1.innerHTML= "1";

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.value="2";
option2.innerHTML= "2";

var option3 = document.createElement("option");
option3.value="3";
option3.innerHTML= "3";

select.addChild(option1);
select.addChild(option2);
select.addChild(option3);

$(select).insertAfter(button);
```

but when it comes to this.
    select.addChild(option1);

chrome browser give me a error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems that addChild does not work here.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: You already have the button in your html?

Comment: sorry, I searched,but haven't find solution,so I post here.and yes ,the button I already have

Comment: You already have the button in your html? Do you need to add it with javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/AKXcF/4/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">   
    <button id="button1">button1</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var div = document.querySelector("#container"),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    select = document.createElement("select");

select.options.add( new Option("Method1","AU", true, true) );
select.options.add( new Option("Method2","FI") );


frag.appendChild(select);
div.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: sorry, I find your answer is correct..I haven't test the code yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.id = "au_1_sel";
select.name="au_1_sel";
select.class=class="searchw8";

var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option.value="AU";
option.selected="";
option.innerHTML= "method1";

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option.value="FI";
option.innerHTML= "method2";

select.addChild(option1);
select.addChild(option2);
document.addChild(select);

var button = document.getElementById("button1");
button.onClick=function(){alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);}
```

Comment: how to undestand this? `select.class = class = "searchw8";`