# Javascript, populate the result of Google maps places API search results into Dropdown list box

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, html-select, dropdown

Help me to save the result of this page into Select / Dropdown list box using Javascript.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

Thanks

Comment: I'm just new with java script .. I don't know how to do that.. this for my learning purpose..

Comment: I have tried to Google it but end up with no results....Please help me... -@taxicala

Comment: please clarify exactly what you are asking. maybe even some pseudo code.

Comment: The above link stores the result (List of hotels in the city when the user types in the city name - with auto complete feature enabled text box) in Table format,  What I need is, how to store that data into drop down list box instead of the Table format. If you can, help me with the Pseudo code.@joeskru

Comment: This smells like homework. here's a hint. look at the function in the code: function addResult(result, i) {}; and this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718753/javascript-to-create-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-selected-value

Comment: Thank you for your help.. @joeskru but I'm unable to understand that code.. if you can send me the code for me? What I need is, Store the Result data into drop down list box instead of the Table format.

Comment: @joeskru I have tried the following code but it shows empty drop down list... 

var div = document.querySelector("#listing"),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    select = document.createElement("select");
 select.options.add( new Option(result.name, i));
 frag.appendChild(select);
 div.appendChild(frag);

Comment: @joeskru please let me know the variable which holds the value of google maps search result (name of the hotel).

Comment: someone please let me know the variable which holds the value of google maps search result (name of the hotel).

I thought that the results is the variable which holds the valuve of available hotel list, but when I use the variable results in the following code it just returns the value as [object object], 

var select = document.getElementById("combo");  
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = results;
  option.value = results;
        select.add(option, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JAVASCRIPT + HTML code [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch):

add this in the body:

```
<div id="drop-container"></div>
```

modify addResult()

```
var div = document.querySelector("#drop-container"),
frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
select = document.createElement("select");

function addResult(result, i) {
    frag.appendChild(select);
    div.appendChild(frag);
    select.options.add( new Option(result.name,result.name));
    select.onclick = function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    };

    //...

};
```