# Putting values in a dropdown using a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a key set that i want to put in the dropdown using a loop.
I want to use select and option tag. How can i do so? your help will be appreciated.I am using only HTML and JS.

Comment: Could you please try using this url: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718753/javascript-to-create-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-selected-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718753/javascript-to-create-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-selected-value)

Comment: do you know anything about jsp pages?

Comment: you can also use java script (JQuery) to load a `<select>` Control with different Values

Comment: @Styl . I know a bit about jsp.

Comment: does anyone know this? if someone hasn't understood the question, there is no need to downvote.

Comment: do you mean `key-set` as a `JSONObject` ? If it is so then you can do it using a foreach loop

Comment: @sumant you probably got the down vote as you haven't shown any attempt to do this yourself.  SO is a forum for if you have attempted something and got stuck with a specific problem.  If you take a tour of the help centre, you will see how to ask a good question and what types of question are on topic for this site - this question appears to be off topic as it is too broad, ie there are too many possible solutions for the question you have asked

Answer (score 0):

Just do a foreach loop and then do a `$('.element').append('<li>Option</li>');` In future, please try to search it properly before you ask, as I have a copy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718753/javascript-to-create-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-selected-value)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-library solution using both objects and arrays as source.

Html:

```
<select id="targetObject"></select>
<select id="targetArray"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
var objOptions = {
    one: "Value One",
    two: "value Two"
};

var objSelect = document.getElementById('targetObject');
var html = "";
for (var key in objOptions) {
    if (!objOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    continue;
  }

  var display = objOptions[key];
  html += "<option value=\"" + key + "\">" + display + "</option>";
}
objSelect.innerHTML = html;



var arrOptions = [
{value: 'one', display: 'Number One'},
{value: 'two', display: 'Number Two'}
];

var arrSelect = document.getElementById('targetArray');
html = "";
for (var i=0; i<arrOptions.length; i++) {
    var value = arrOptions[i].value;
  var display = arrOptions[i].display;
  html += "<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + display + "</option>";
}
arrSelect.innerHTML = html;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aoLvuku4/