# Using JS to auto append new rows based off input selection

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, mustache

I am looking to add functionality similar to what expedia and hotels.com and other similar sites do when you select the number of rooms it will give you an option for how many adults and children per room. If you choose children it will allow you to select the ages per child as well. Please see image below as an example. I am willing to use something like Handlebars or mustache.

For working example visit [example](https://www.travelocity.com/).

The first image shows before selecting multiple rooms or children.
[image: The first image shows before selecting multiple rooms or children.]

The second image shows multiple rooms and children selected.
[image: The second image shows multiple rooms and children selected.]

Comment: yes you need to create elements dynamic based on the ddl selected number see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718753/javascript-to-create-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-selected-value , what the exact issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

1. Create a template for a room
2. Create another template for the children ages.

Then after the number of rooms is selected you render as many room templates as the number of rooms.

Then you repeat the same process for the ages of the children.

The piece of data you need to be careful with is the attribute name or id of each of the inputs inserted by the templates because that needs to match with the way your backend will deserialize the form.

Some frameworks like .net mvc have conventions like if you are going to post an array of objects the "name" attribute has to be like

```
name = "[X].Adults"
```

Let me know if you need a code sample to further explain what I said above but if you follow the steps I mentioned you should be able to develop the form very quickly.

---- new ----

Find below a link with a simple example of what I was explaining above. Keep in mind that this is a mockup but will be very similar to what you need to do:

https://codepen.io/santiagobenitez/pen/ZJxMJP

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was thinking but I do need a code sample. I was thinking I would need a <div id="room"> and <div id="children"> 

Thanks!

Comment: @f1ss1on I have added a code example with a mockup of the work you need to do. Let me know if it makes sense